# Adding Page Templates to post but it ignored it

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, templates, metabox

I follow the post to add the template metabox to a custom post type's editor, but it doesn't work. When I visit the post, it shows "NOT FOUND ANY POST" which looks like `index.php` or `single.php` template react to a non-exist post link.

```
function IUI_post_template_meta_box($post) {
    if ('contest' == $post->post_type && 0 != count(get_post_templates())) {
        $template = get_post_meta($post->ID,'页面模版',true);
        ?>
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="post_template">模版</label>
        <select name="post_template" id="post_template">
            <option value="default">（空）</option>
            <?php post_template_dropdown($template); ?>
        </select>
        <?php
    }
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes','add_post_template_metabox');
function add_post_template_metabox() {
    add_meta_box('post_template_box', 'Template', 'IUI_post_template_meta_box', 'contest', 'side', 'core');
}

function get_post_templates() {
    $theme = wp_get_theme();
    $templates = $theme['Template Files'];
    $post_templates = array();

    if ( is_array( $templates ) ) {
        $base = array( trailingslashit(get_template_directory()), trailingslashit(get_stylesheet_directory()) );

        foreach ( $templates as $template ) {
            $basename = str_replace($base, '', $template);
            if ($basename != 'functions.php') {
        // allow template files in subdirectories
                if ( false !== strpos($basename, '/') )
                    continue;

                $template_data = implode( '', file( $template ));

                $name = '';
                if ( preg_match( '|Post Template:(.*)$|mi', $template_data, $name ) )
                    $name = _cleanup_header_comment($name[1]);

                if ( !empty( $name ) ) {
                    $post_templates[trim( $name )] = $basename;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $post_templates;
}

function post_template_dropdown( $default = '' ) {
    $templates = get_post_templates();
    ksort( $templates );
    foreach (array_keys( $templates ) as $template )
        : if ( $default == $templates[$template] )
    $selected = " selected='selected'";
    else
        $selected = '';
    echo "\n\t<option value='".$templates[$template]."' $selected>$template</option>";
    endforeach;
}


add_filter('single_template','IuI_get_post_template_for_template_loader');
function IuI_get_post_template_for_template_loader($template) {
    // global $wp_query;
    // $post = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    // global $post;
    // $template = get_stylesheet_directory() . "/single-test.php";

    if ($post->post_type == 'contest') {
        $post_template = get_post_meta($post->ID,'页面模版',true);
        if (!empty($post_template) && $post_template!='default') {

        }
        $template = get_stylesheet_directory() . "/single-test.php";
            // $template = get_stylesheet_directory() . "/{$post_template}";
    }
    return $template;
}
```

the custom post type named "contest", the permalink is like dev.photoworld.com.cn/contest/POST-ID